# Erro ao buscar string dentro de outra string em python

Tags: python

Estou fazendo alguns testes e o codigo aparenta estar correto logicamente, mas quando uso um exemplo: "que dia é hoje?" como self.frase ele só me retorna o primeiro if (das horas), se eu botar como self.frase = "Que dia da semana é hoje?" o mesmo erro acontece, onde estou errando?

```
def about_time(self):
    temp_atual = datetime.datetime.now()
    if 'são' or 'sao' in self.frase:
        print("Agora são " + str(temp_atual.hour) + " horas, " + str(temp_atual.minute) + " minutos e " + str(temp_atual.second) + " segundos.")
    elif 'dia' and 'hoje' in self.frase:
        print("Hoje é dia " + str(temp_atual.day) + "/" + str(temp_atual.month) + "/" + str(temp_atual.year))
    elif 'dia da semana' in self.frase:
        dia = temp_atual.isoweekday()
        if dia == 1:
            dia = "segunda-feira"
        if dia == 2:
            dia = "terça-feira"
        if dia == 3:
            dia = "quarta-feira"
        if dia == 4:
            dia = "quinta-feira"
        if dia == 5:
            dia = "sexta-feira"
        if dia == 6:
            dia = "sábado"
        if dia == 7:
            dia = "domingo"
        print("Hoje é " + dia)
```

Comment: Isso esta errado `'são' or 'sao' in self.frase`, teria que ser `'são' in self.frase or 'sao' in self.frase`... esse também esta errado `'dia' and 'hoje' in self.frase:`, deveria ser `'dia' in self.frase and 'hoje' in self.frase:`

Comment: não posso passar dois parametros de uma fez no caso do "in self.frase"? Pensei que eu poderia, assim seria mais simples. Mas obrigado!

Comment: Não é essa a questão, a questão é que OR e AND são operadores lógico, eles não funcionam dentro de `in`, o que esta entre eles são coisas separadas, ou seja antes do `OR` é uma checagem, após o OR é outra checagem, o mesmo vale para AND, só que muda apenas o comportamento, mas ainda sim as operações lógicas são separadas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seus ifs estão incorretos, **`and` e `or` são operadores lógicos**, eles não fazem parte do `in`, portanto isto esta errado:

```
if 'são' or 'sao' in self.frase
```

Deveria ser:

```
if 'são' in self.frase or 'sao' in self.frase
```

Este também esta errado

```
if 'dia' and 'hoje' in self.frase:
```

deveria ser

```
if 'dia' in self.frase and 'hoje' in self.frase:
```

Cada `or` ou `and` separam instruções para operações lógicas, ou seja eles não trabalham dentro do `in`, mas sim "ao contrário", então o uso é este:

```
if <instrução> or <outra instrução>:
```

Em cada um destas instruções você pode usar usar `==`, `!=`, `is`, `is not`, mas são instruções a parte, então no seu primeiro `if` é como se estivesse fazendo isso:

```
if ('são') or ('sao' in self.frase)
```

Checa primeiro se `'são'` se falhasse checaria `'sao' in self.frase`, como `'são'` sempre passa no `if`, então mesmo que a frase estivesse diferente ele entraria de qualquer forma, pois `'são'` não estava sendo comparado a nada.

Answer (score 2):

Dei uma pequena refatorada no seu código:

```
def about_time(self):
    temp_atual = datetime.datetime.now()
    if any(_ in self.frase for _ in ('sao', 'são')):
        print(temp_atual.strftime("Agora são %H horas, %M minutos e %S segundos."))
    elif 'dia' in self.frase:
      if 'hoje' in self.frase:
        print(temp_atual.strftime("Hoje é dia %d/%m/%Y"))
      elif 'semana' in self.frase:
        dia = [None, 'segunda-feira', 'terça-feira',
        'quarta-feira', 'quinta-feira', 'sexta-feira',
        'sábado', 'domingo'][temp_atual.isoweekday()]
        print("Hoje é " + dia)
```

Já que `isoweekday()` retorna um valor entre 1 e 7, botei um None na lista no índice 0, mas, poderia ser qualquer coisa...
Aí acessamos a lista de dias pelo índice (1 a 7, lembra?), que também poderia ser escrito como um dicionário:

```
dia = {i: dia for i, dia in enumerate(['segunda-feira', 'terça-feira',
                                       'quarta-feira', 'quinta-feira', 
                                       'sexta-feira', 'sábado', 'domingo'], start=1)}.get(temp_atual.isoweekday())
```

qualquer uma dessas formas nos poupa daquele bloco gigante de `ifs/elifs`.

Também recomendo de uma olhada no método `strftime()` do objeto `datetime`, facilita lidar com strings e datas.

*Edit: Adicionando a explicação da função `any()` a pedido do OP*

A função `any()` recebe um iterável e retorna `True` se **qualquer elemento** daquele iterável for *equivalente* a `True`, no caso:

```
(_ in self.frase for _ in ('sao', 'são'))
# é parecido a:
compares = []
for palavra in ('sao', 'são'):
  if palavra == self.frase:
    compares.append(True)
  else:
    compares.append(False)
```

o iterável seria um gerador de 2 elementos `('sao', 'são')` comparados contra `self.frase`, se consideramos `self.frase = 'teste'` o gerador seria parecido a: `(False, False)` já que nenhuma das 2 palavras é igual a `self.frase`, e como **nenhum** dos elementos é igual a `True`, não entramos no `if`.

Existe também uma função parecida, `all()`, a diferença sendo que `all()` só retorna `True` se **todos os elementos** forem *equivalentes* a `True`.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor essa linha: `if any(_ in self.frase for _ in ('sao', 'são')):`? Obrigado pela resposta, gostei da otimização.

Comment: Se não tiver ficado claro, me avise que reescrevo.

Answer (score -2):

```
    import datetime

def about_time(message):
    temp_atual = datetime.datetime.now()
    if 'são' or 'sao' in message:
        print("Agora são " + str(temp_atual.hour) + " horas, " + str(temp_atual.minute) + " minutos e " + str(temp_atual.second) + " segundos.")
        if 'dia' and 'hoje' in message:
            print("Hoje é dia " + str(temp_atual.day) + "/" + str(temp_atual.month) + "/" + str(temp_atual.year))
            if 'dia da semana' in message:
                dia = temp_atual.isoweekday()
                if dia == 1:
                    dia = "segunda-feira"
                if dia == 2:
                    dia = "terça-feira"
                if dia == 3:
                    dia = "quarta-feira"
                if dia == 4:
                    dia = "quinta-feira"
                if dia == 5:
                    dia = "sexta-feira"
                if dia == 6:
                    dia = "sábado"
                if dia == 7:
                    dia = "domingo"
                print("Hoje é " + dia)
about_time('Que dia é hoje?')
```

OUTPUT:

```
Agora são 0 horas, 18 minutos e 45 segundos.
Hoje é dia 9/7/2018
```

Comment: Se esta é uma solução ao problema da pergunta, poderia descrever em palavras o que você fez? Um código que pode ser trivial para você pode não ser para outros usuários.